# spec2 tests failing for scalatra app with swagger support

Tags: scala, specs2, scalatra, swagger

When calling a prototypical spec3 test case on a scalatra app with swagger support, the tests  fail.

Here's the test/spec code:
ServletSpec.scala

```
class ServletSpec extends ScalatraSpec { def is =
  "Calling the generated swagger client"        ^
    "should return success"                     ! swaggerClient^
                                                end

  addServlet(classOf[TestController], "/api/*")

  def swaggerClient = get("/api/account") {
    status must_== 200
    response.body must_== 
      """my json response"""
  }  
}
```

The TestController looks like:
    package com.newco

```
import org.scalatra._
import org.scalatra.swagger._

//sample - see http://www.scalatra.org/guides/swagger.html

// JSON-related libraries
import org.json4s.{DefaultFormats, Formats}

// JSON handling support from Scalatra
import org.scalatra.json._

class TestController(implicit val swagger: Swagger) extends ScalatraServlet 
    with JacksonJsonSupport  with JValueResult {

  protected val applicationName = Some("AppName")
  protected val applicationDescription = "description."

   // Sets up automatic case class to JSON output serialization
  protected implicit val jsonFormats: Formats = DefaultFormats

  // Before every action runs, set the content type to be in JSON format.
  before() {
    contentType = formats("json")
  }

  val getAccount = 
    (apiOperation[GetAccountResponse]("getAccount")
      summary "Get users account information"
      notes "Returns the users profile"
      parameter queryParam[AccessToken]("accessToken").description("Access token returned from authentication service")
      )

  get("/account", operation(getAccount)){
      SampleData.getAccountResponse
  }
}
```

sbt test fails with the following error (no detailed trace available):
    [error] x should return success
    [error]    '
    [error]    
    [error]    
    [error]    Error 500 com.acme.TestController
    [error]    
    [error]    
    [error]

### HTTP ERROR: 500

[error]

Problem accessing /api/account. Reason:
    [error]

```
    com.acme.TestController
```

[error]

---

*Powered by Jetty://*
    [error]
    [error]    
    [error]    
    [error]    '
    [error]     is not equal to 
    ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to change the spec2 line from:

```
addServlet(classOf[TestController], "api/*")
```

to:

```
implicit val swagger = new GPNSwagger 
addServlet(new TestController, "/api/*")
```

Swagger annotation causes the controller class to be abstract and cannot be instantiated as the declared type.  This alternate method of mapping the servlet works